# How can I add content to a webpage?

Tags: python, flask, pycharm

I've been learning some basic python syntax but am now embarking on a 'project'. I'm using Flask and Pycharm and have created a simple web page. If I go to http://127.0.0.1:5000/ I can see 'Home Page' is displayed.

How would I go about adding more content to the page? e.g. maybe some user input boxes or creating a login page - that type of thing.

Thanks in advance

I've searched various tutorials for information but I'm confused about how to proceed from here. The code I currently have in a file call app.py is as follows:

```
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def home():
return ('<h1>Home Page</h1>')

if __name__ == '__main__':
app.run()
```

Comment: Read [Flask docs](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/), in particular the bits about "Static files" and "Rendering Templates". ("Various tutorials" are almost always inferior to the official documentation.)

Comment: [Tutorial flask web page  content](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/how-to-build-a-web-application-using-flask-and-deploy-it-to-the-cloud-3551c985e492/) follow this tutorial to run flask, and see  html output

Comment: By using the link supplied to the tutorial on free code camp I have managed to get a little bit further and can see some html output. Thanks